# show components based on user role in react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, jwt, token

I want to show a component and it's icon based on user role and I'm using react/redux but I don't know how to do this. I have to get the decoded user token for this.
the component privateRoute:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/settings" component={waitFor(Settings)} />
```

and my action :

```
export const getUser = () => {
if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
    return jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('token'))
}}
export const getUserInfo = (userData)=>dispatch=>{
const userData =  jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('token'))
dispatch({
        type: userConstants.GET_USER_DATA,
        payload : userData
    
    })}
```

and it is my reducer:

```
const initState = {
 userData: {

   },
 };
 const userReducers = (state = initState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
     case userConstants:
  return null;

case userConstants.GET_USER_DATA:
    return {
      ...state, 
      userData: action.payload
    }

default:
  return state
  }}
```

I want to have the icon in this sidebar component :

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        userRoles: [],
        listItems: [
            
            {
                listText: 'setting',
                listIcon: SettingIcon,
                expan: true,
                isExpanded: false,
                route: '',
                key: "Setting",
               
                 ///otheritems...

        ],
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    let userData = this.props.getUser();
    if (userData && userData.role) {
        this.setState({ userRoles: userData.role })
    }

    
}
   }

    render(){
        return(
                 <div>{{this.state.listItems.map((item, index) => {
                                let flag = true;
                                if (item.key === 'Setting' && this.state.userRoles.length &&
                                    !this.state.userRoles
                                        .map((rol) => rol)
                                        .includes("Admin")

                                ) {
                                    flag = false;}if(flag){
                                     <img src={item.listIcon} />
                       }}
               </div>)}



const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
     openSideBar: state.openSideBar , 
     userInfo : state.userInfo
    };};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
logout: () => dispatch(logout()),
getUser: () => getUser(),
getUserInfo : () => dispatch(getUserInfo())

  });
```

I've written the code again so please don't mind the syntax

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not copy data from reducer state into local state. Single source of truth must be maintained
2. You already have `userInfo` that comes from `mapStateToProps` and can be accessed inside the code with use of `this.props.userInfo`
3. Inside `componentDidMount` call `this.props.getUser()` without taking anything from it, as it will settle down in your reducer state

Then simply just check for role in props (that comes from state machine) and render things accordingly. If you require additional info, I will add it under this answer.
Just do not forget to add guard clause to prevent app from crashing if actual data is still not in state machine.

```
render() { if (!this.props.userInfo) return null . . .
```

Comment: thank you so much. as I am a beginner, can you give me more information about how exactly to access user role? and is my action and reducer correct?

Comment: It actually depends on what object is constructed via `jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('token'))`, you can console log it to see what structure it has.

Comment: how can i get that? when I console.log my userInfo I get nothing... and is my reducer and action correct?

Comment: I have little to no experience on thunk actions, but does jwt decode part work? You can console.log inside action to see. Best thing I always suggest is to use React Developer Tools https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi and Redux DevTools https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd